# format excel file after export-csv powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

Brand new to powershell and trying to modify an existing script.

There is a line that exports a csv file.

```
Get-Devices $accountID | Export-Csv -Path $DevicesCSV -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

and It does what it is supposed to do and I get a file in the path specified...

What I want to do is make the file look pretty, make it into a table in excel so columns can be sorted.  Add formatting, etc.
I do not see any options to do that and need some guidance on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

There are some workarounds, but the easiest way would be to use dedicated module for this, such as [ImportExcel by dfinke](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel). It allows you to work with Excel files both ways (importing/exporting).

[Get-Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-6) is your friend if you want to learn more about what specific cmdlets like `Export-Excel` could do.

If you want to sort the data, you can do this before exporting, using [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.